# How can I display image as color managed with wxPython?

Tags: python, linux, wxpython, color-profile, color-management

I want to show images with embedded ICC profile with wxPython. To show them correctly, they need to be converted to the current display profile.

Is there a way to get wxPython automatically do the conversion?

If not, how can I get the display profile to do the conversion myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the current display profile information is available in two places.

- It can be queried directly from colord: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/colord/using.html.
- It can be found from _ICC_PROFILE X property: http://www.oyranos.org/wiki/index.php?title=ICC_Profiles_in_X_Specification_0.4